# Is it possible to reuse Axis2 beans for a CXF service implementation?

Tags: maven, cxf, apache-axis

I'm adding a CXF interface to my Axis2 web application, and was wondering if it was possible to use all the generated Axis2 beans instead of having 2 sets.

Right now, I've maneuvered the project enough to the point that it compiles (using maven), but when starting it up in tomcat I get a lot of these errors:

```
@XmlAttribute/@XmlValue need to reference a Java type that maps to text in XML.
```

This error comes from the Axis2 beans, and I'm guessing it's due to the fact that Axis2 adds @XmlAttribute annotations in its generated sources.  My question is, is there an easier way to use Axis2 beans with CXF?  Is it even possible?  Would commenting out the @XmlAttribute lines before compilation fix my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a maven-antrun-plugin task to find and replace `@Xml` with `//@Xml` seemed to work.  I haven't tested the independent services, but they are both running without errors.  If anyone has a better solution, I'm all ears.  Mine seems a little hacky.